# How to find that how much time phone took to download a file from internet

Tags: android

I want to write code that will give me the time it took to download a file(speciallly an app)
from internet.
More specifically I want to know the downloading speed of last downloaded app.

So I thouhgt to find the time for downloading and then divide the file size by time ,I will get the speed.

can anyone help me in finding the time it took to download a file from internet.

Comment: are you talking about files downloaded with your app?

Comment: no, file downloaded by  download manager.

Comment: By  ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE I can know the time when the download completed, But how to find when the download started.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at [`TrafficStats`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) class in `Android` which :

> Class that provides network traffic statistics. These statistics include bytes transmitted and received and network packets transmitted and received, over all interfaces, over the mobile interface, and on a per-UID basis.

I did not used this class, but I think it can do what you are trying to achieve.